# Where can I set up caching with the Baqend Community edition?

Tags: angular, baqend

I've installed the community edition of Baqend for Linux. It works great, however, I didn't find any option to setup the caching in the Baqend CDN and the browser.

Am I missing something? I would love to serve my static Angular 2 assets and my JSON objects from the cache to improve page load time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the caching is only available in Baqend Cloud and Enterprise.

The two limitations of the community edition are:

- No automatic caching
- No horizontal scaling of the application layer

A good solution to using both caching and the community edition is to develop with the community edition and push to Baqend Cloud for production to enable CDN and browser caching.

A workaround would be to put a [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org) in front of the Baqend server to cache manually. However, the cache will not be updated automatically, so this only makes sense if you do not have the option to use the cloud or licensed version.